# For loop setting two matching variables

Tags: windows, batch-file, for-loop, command-line

I need a batch to zip a specific folder inside all the users' profiles.

This is what I have for now, however, I can't think of a way to set the **%user%** variable to match with each loop.

```
set ZIPFILE=C:\BKP\%user%.zip
for /d %%a in (
  "C:\Users\*"
) do (set "logFolder=%%~fa\AppData\Local\Intuit\QuickBooks\Log\27.0\" & call :woot)

:woot
"c:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a %ZIPFILE% "%logFolder%"
```

I was able to get a "list" of all users using this line

```
dir /b /ad "C:\Users"
```

and now I need to find a way to make the loop to change the variable **%user%** with every loop, for example, the output should be:

7z.exe a C:\BKP\**User1**.zip C:\Users\**User1**\AppData\Local\Intuit\QuickBooks\Log\27.0\

7z.exe a C:\BKP\**User2**.zip C:\Users\**User2**\AppData\Local\Intuit\QuickBooks\Log\27.0\

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change to the users folder first, you can just loop on the folders and use the loop variable.

```
c:
cd \Users
for /d %%a in ("*") do (
    set ZIPFILE=C:\BKP\%%a.zip &
    set "logFolder=c:\Users\%%a\AppData\Local\Intuit\QuickBooks\Log\27.0\" &
    call :woot)

:woot
"c:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a %ZIPFILE% "%logFolder%"
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed! Sometimes the solution is so simple that it makes us feel dumb :P Thanks a lot.